# Syntax of nested "if else" in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am strugging a bit to implement a nested if else expressions in SML. Can anyone highlight its syntax. Suppose there are three conditions C1, C2, C3 I need equivalent of following in C code.

```
if (C1) { 
    return true;
}
else {
    if(C2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
         if (C3) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but its treated as "if, else if, and else" cases

```
if C1 then true
else if C2 then true
else if C3 then true
else false
```

Comment: 'its treated as "if, else if, and else" cases' What do you mean by that? Your C code is "if, else if, else", too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*You're correct. Two code fragments are equivalent.*

With a bit of indentation, your SML example looks more like using nested `if/else`:

```
if C1 then true
else
    if C2 then true
    else
        if C3 then true
        else false
```

You could also use parentheses so that SML example looks almost the same as C example but it isn't necessary.

Of course, the most idiomatic way in SML is to write

```
C1 orelse C2 orelse C3
```

You could use the same trick for your C code. Remember that returning `true/false` in `if/else` blocks is code smell.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that using `orelse` is the right way to go here, but just as an alternative to situations where you want to act on more complex combinations, pattern matching would be able to help you.

```
fun funtrue (false,false,false) = false
  | funtrue _                   = true
```

or as a case statement

```
case (C1,C2,C3) of
     (false,false,false) => false
  |  _                   => true
```